# Is it possible to access headers like :authority: sent by browser when using HTTP2 in Springboot app

Tags: spring-mvc

It is possible to enable HTTP2 support in Springboot application like so:

`server.http2.enabled=true`

with this enabled and with embedded Tomcat running in HTTPS mode (at port 8443), the browsers (like Chrome) use the HTTP2 (shown as h2 in protocol column of Chrome devtools network panel), and due to the specs related to HTTP2 do not send the `Host: localhost:8443` header. Instead the browsers send `:authority: localhost:8443`. Unfortunately when you access headers in the MVC controller handler method headers like `:authority:` are not accessible. And of course `Host:` header is also not available, because the browser did not send it (duh).

If I turn on the logging to TRACE level like this:

`logging.level.org.apache.coyote.http2.stream: trace`

I do see log messages like this:

`2023-10-17T16:08:06.936-07:00 DEBUG 22116 --- [nio-8090-exec-9] org.apache.coyote.http2.HpackDecoder     : Emitting header with name [:authority] and value [localhost:8443]`

which tells me that the header did make it to the embedded Tomcat in the Springboot app.

Issue:

Some of the upstream processing depends on the presence of `Host:` header. For example, the Spring Gloud Gateway ProxyExchange (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/51367a8668c686e972f621874ec8e40ae21b56b2/spring-cloud-gateway-mvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/mvc/ProxyExchange.java#L417) uses it to generate the `forwarded:` header. This header in turn is used by the backend APIs implemented using HATEOAS to generate the link rels.

QUESTION:

- Is it possible to detect that the client sent the `HttpServletRequest` over HTTP2 protcol?
- Is it possible to get access to the low level(?) `:authority:` header. In fact I would have expected Spring to (optionally) do some conversion from `:authority:` header and convert it to `Host:` header because upstream processing could then just work off of `Host:` header. If I could get hold of `:authority:` header I could write a filter to do this.
- Has anyone run into this issue and how did you solve it?

Comment: It turns out `org.apache.coyote.http2.Stream#parseAuthority` parses the `:authority:` header and uses it to set the values for `request.getServerName()` and `request.getServerPort()`. Therefore those can be used to restore the `Host:` header by implementing a filter to keep the rest of handling of `Host:` header as is.